# Java Console input and print a GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Hi i'm a java student beginner I can't get how to input by console a date using GregorianCalendar and print it like:
Input: 12/10/1994
Output: 12/10/1994

Comment: and what do you know?

Comment: What does the program do? Does it just print what they put in?

Comment: is this an applet assignment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go

```
String format="MM/dd/yyyy";

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.nextLine();//now the program waits for input
Date d= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("12/10/1994");
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);

String output=new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(cal.getTime());
```

`cal` is your gregorian calendar.